# how to run the quartz scheduler as soon as I started the server in JBOSS5.1.1

Tags: jboss5.x

Currently I have added the quartz-1.8.6 and quartz-jboss-1.8.6 jars and quartz-    service.xml file in jboss5.1.1 and i have added the quartz1.8.6 related jar files in the EAR application and I have return the code as follows:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException, IOException {
try {
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
SchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory();
Scheduler sched = sf.getScheduler();
JobDetail job = new JobDetail("job1", "group1", SimpleJob.class);
CronTrigger trigger = new CronTrigger("trigger1", "group1", "job1", "group1", "0/5 * * * * ?");
sched.addJob(job, true);
Date ft = sched.scheduleJob(trigger);
try
{
 Thread.activeCount();
catch (Exception e)
 {
}
sched.start();
} 
catch (Exception exc){ 
exc.printStackTrace();
}
.....
}
```

but this code is running successfully once i logged in the link ...but i needed it to run the crontask once the server started